# when should I return value instead of modifying receiver pointer?

Tags: go

I have a method for the struct **ProofOfWork** which should modify the struct members **Nonce** and **Hash**. So I wonder whether it should modify these two members of the given instance inside the method **Run** or should make these two variables as a return.

So here is the method **Run** with return variables:

```
// Run performs a proof-of-work
func (pow *ProofOfWork) Run() (int, []byte) {
    var hashInt big.Int
    var hash [32]byte
    nonce := 0

    fmt.Printf("Mining the block containing \"%s\"\n", pow.block.Data)
    for nonce < maxNonce {
        data := pow.prepareData(nonce)

        hash = sha256.Sum256(data)
        fmt.Printf("\r%x", hash)
        hashInt.SetBytes(hash[:])

        if hashInt.Cmp(pow.target) == -1 {
            break
        } else {
            nonce++
        }
    }
    fmt.Print("\n\n")

    return nonce, hash[:]
}
```

Then the version without any return variables:

```
func (pow *ProofOfWork) Run() {
    var hashInt big.Int
    var hash [32]byte // the type of hash value is defined by result of the sha256 function
    nonce := 0

    for nonce < MaxNonce {
        data := pow.prepareData(nonce)
        hash := sha256.Sum256(data)
        hashInt.SetBytes(hash[:])
        if hashInt.Cmp(pow.target) == -1 {
            // the nonce found
            break
        } else {
            nonce++
        }
    }
    pow.block.Hash = hash[:]
    pow.block.Nonce = nonce
}
```

Comment: answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions. This one doesn't depend on opinion. It depends on purpose. To one who vote to close

Comment: In your second approach, `pow.block` seems like an unexported field. Is it on purpose?

Comment: If a method is called run I would not expect return values (exept of an error).

Comment: @leafbebop In fact, the block is wrapped inside the pow as **pow.block** and then it will be completed after the **Run** of **ProofOfWork**. And then the block will be returned after the function **Run**.

Answer (score 0):

Both options you show might be useful sometimes. May I propose another possibility. In Go we should use functions much more often then in other languages. A plain function might be exactly what you are looking for:

```
// Run performs a proof-of-work
func Run(pow *ProofOfWork) (int, []byte) {
    var hashInt big.Int
    var hash [32]byte
    nonce := 0

    fmt.Printf("Mining the block containing \"%s\"\n", pow.block.Data)
    for nonce < maxNonce {
        data := pow.prepareData(nonce)

        hash = sha256.Sum256(data)
        fmt.Printf("\r%x", hash)
        hashInt.SetBytes(hash[:])

        if hashInt.Cmp(pow.target) == -1 {
            break
        } else {
            nonce++
        }
    }
    fmt.Print("\n\n")

    return nonce, hash[:]
}
```

I would probably make ProofOfWork an interface, and abstract Run that way.

Comment: Thanks for the proposal. But I think the method **Run** is a behavior of **ProofOfWork**. Because it will not always return the same variables regarding to the different **ProofOfWork**.